# MySQL 8.0.3 database not starting after power outage

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL 8.0.3 database, which I can't start, after a power outage. Unfortunately I have been very stupid and made any backups (I know you are more than welcome to laugh at me).

The database is rather big (108GB).

The errors from my log is the following:

```
2023-08-07T04:56:09.808512Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.23.04.4) starting as process 27754
2023-08-07T04:56:09.812392Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=1073741824. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2023-08-07T04:56:09.813156Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-08-07T04:56:10.045881Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013881] [InnoDB] The redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo72019 has start_lsn 381918225408 but expected 382023017472 (end_lsn of the previous redo log file).
2023-08-07T04:56:10.045913Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-08-07T04:56:10.522340Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-08-07T04:56:10.522495Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-08-07T04:56:10.522525Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-07T04:56:10.522975Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.23.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
```

Below is a list of all files:

```
 auto.cnf        binlog.000401   binlog.000419   binlog.000437   binlog.000455   binlog.000473   binlog.000491     client-key.pem       ibtmp1                     nextcloud_24             undo_002
 binlog.000384   binlog.000402   binlog.000420   binlog.000438   binlog.000456   binlog.000474   binlog.000492     cms                 '#innodb_redo'              nextcloud_25             voucher
 binlog.000385   binlog.000403   binlog.000421   binlog.000439   binlog.000457   binlog.000475   binlog.000493     cms_borchsvej       '#innodb_temp'              nextcloud_cloud          wordpress
 binlog.000386   binlog.000404   binlog.000422   binlog.000440   binlog.000458   binlog.000476   binlog.000494     cms_ga               kjcdk                      nextcloud_test           wordpress_default
 binlog.000387   binlog.000405   binlog.000423   binlog.000441   binlog.000459   binlog.000477   binlog.000495     cms_ladida           kjcdk_nextcloud            okitcms                  wordpress_forening
 binlog.000388   binlog.000406   binlog.000424   binlog.000442   binlog.000460   binlog.000478   binlog.000496     cms_strapi           laravel@002dtdd            performance_schema       wordpress_kingstoft
 binlog.000389   binlog.000407   binlog.000425   binlog.000443   binlog.000461   binlog.000479   binlog.000497     cms_woocommerce      laravel_test               private_key.pem          wordpress_ladida
 binlog.000390   binlog.000408   binlog.000426   binlog.000444   binlog.000462   binlog.000480   binlog.000498     cms_wordpress        lean@002dmysql@002djoins   public_key.pem           wordpress_mestrenesloge
 binlog.000391   binlog.000409   binlog.000427   binlog.000445   binlog.000463   binlog.000481   binlog.000499     compito              lms                        sakila                   wordpress_woocommerce
 binlog.000392   binlog.000410   binlog.000428   binlog.000446   binlog.000464   binlog.000482   binlog.000500     courses              matomo                     scorelogger_production   wp
 binlog.000393   binlog.000411   binlog.000429   binlog.000447   binlog.000465   binlog.000483   binlog.000501     DotNetCoreMySql      MusicStoreDB               semaphore                wp_default
 binlog.000394   binlog.000412   binlog.000430   binlog.000448   binlog.000466   binlog.000484   binlog.000502     edu                  mydb                       server-cert.pem          wp_kingstoft
 binlog.000395   binlog.000413   binlog.000431   binlog.000449   binlog.000467   binlog.000485   binlog.index      [redacted]               my_fake_n2n_database       server-key.pem           wp_mestrenesloge
 binlog.000396   binlog.000414   binlog.000432   binlog.000450   binlog.000468   binlog.000486   ca-key.pem        [redacted]       mysql                      smarthome                wp_woocommerce
 binlog.000397   binlog.000415   binlog.000433   binlog.000451   binlog.000469   binlog.000487   ca.pem           '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'   mysql.ibd                  sys
 binlog.000398   binlog.000416   binlog.000434   binlog.000452   binlog.000470   binlog.000488   cargrade         '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'   mysql.sock                 templates
 binlog.000399   binlog.000417   binlog.000435   binlog.000453   binlog.000471   binlog.000489   cargrade_dev      ib_buffer_pool       mysql_upgrade_info         test
 binlog.000400   binlog.000418   binlog.000436   binlog.000454   binlog.000472   binlog.000490   client-cert.pem   ibdata1              nextcloud                  undo_001
```

All suggestions I have found, ask to delete `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`, but those files does not exists or logging on the Mysql, but I can't start it, so I can't really login to the server.

I can't find a solution to the capacity of the `#ib_redo72019`, I tried removing it, which wasn't a good idea, which I guess is the file with the issue, but I really don't know that file.

Are there any bright minds who can help me get further. Thank you in advanced :)

---

UPDATE:

I just tested with another version and now I have this, so I am not sure the database can be saved.

```
2023-08-08 13:59:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.
2023-08-08 13:59:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-08-08 13:59:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.
2023-08-08T13:59:57.409637Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 1
2023-08-08T13:59:57.425136Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-08-08T13:59:59.826527Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011906] [InnoDB] Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of page [page id: space=0, page number=5]. You may have to recover from a backup.
```

Comment: See [Failed to start MySQL due to start_lsn and end_lsn issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/330030/mysql-8-0-3-database-not-starting-after-power-outage)

Comment: I guess you meant to link to this page [https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,705633,705633](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,705633,705633), I have tried to follow it, but the suggestions could not help fixing the issue.